# Javascript: records to be displayed in new line when there are more than one record

Tags: javascript

Please help me with this.

This is my code to get role, first name and last name from a database. If there are more than one record, the results should get printed in a new line. I tried adding '\n' and `<br>` tags to get the data to a new line but it didn't work. I tried for loop but it pulls the records more than once and I get duplicate values as below.

```
ObjAssociatedPartyLocal_tab = variable for first name and last name
ObjAssociatedPartyRole_tab = variable for the role of that person
```

The result I'm getting is

```
testrole1 : Test_Last, Test_First testrole1 : testlast2, testfirst2 testrole2 : Test_Last, Test_First testrole2 : testlast2, testfirst2
```

However, it should be displayed like this,

```
testrole1 : Test_Last, Test_First,
testrole2 : testlast2, testfirst2
```

The code I wrote is,

```
maker = "";             
for(var i=0; i < data.ObjAssociatedPartyRole_tab.length; i++)               
{                   
  if (data.ObjAssociatedPartyLocal_tab !== null && 
  data.ObjAssociatedPartyLocal_tab !== ''){                     
    for(var j=0; j < data.ObjAssociatedPartyRole_tab.length; j++){                              
    maker += data.ObjAssociatedPartyRole_tab[i] + " : " + data.ObjAssociatedPartyLocal_tab[j] + "\n";                       
    }                           
  }                 
}
```

Comment: Are you using html to print out the results? Can you also add here the html part if this is the case.

Comment: Sorry, this is fully written in Javascript

Comment: Have you checked that the results from the database are correct? Meaning that these 2 data objects contain the right data.

Comment: Where are you printing these values? To the console?